# Displaying Euro Symbol with JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl, euro

I have text in a mysql database which is correctly holding the Euro symbol. What I am trying to do is create an array entry in javascript that will be used to populate a text area when a user selects an option from a drop down. Currently what I have is:

```
var cannedResponses = new Object();
<c:forEach items="${pageModel.cannedResponses}" var="cannedResponse" varStatus="status">
cannedResponses["${cannedResponse.id}"] = "${cannedResponse.response}";
</c:forEach>
```

This adds all of the canned responses to the array but when I view source I can already see that the Euro symbol is a ?, and when it populates the text area it is still a ?. I can see when debugging that the Euro symbol is correctly set in the response String in the servlet so I know it is correct until this point.

Any help in how to make this appear correctly when loaded into the HTML would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem appears to be the character encoding of the returned file.  The question mark indicates that it's ASCII, but you should set it to UTF-8.  There are several settings you need to check: 1) the encoding settings of the JSPs served by your web/app server, 2) the actual encoding of the jsp file on the file system (use features of Notepad++ or Textpad to check the encoding of the file). 3) the encoding set inside the jsp itself.

Comment: And you can check the Collation of the database too. Set it to latin_swedish_ci or utf8_general_ci if its not already.

Comment: I was missing the following line in my JSP to set the encoding to UTF-8 <%@page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>. Thanks for your help